# Vector arrow is not on the letter but shifted to left

Tags: math-operators, mathtools, vector

I'm trying to type a vector notation over a letter but it ends up with a failure. It looks like the vector arrow and the letter I want to make a vector take two different spaces.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item $\vec{\omega} = (0,0,-1.6 \times 10^{5})\ \mathrm{s^{-1}}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT

And here's the output from Atom compared to a more common PDF viwer:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. I can't reproduce your issue from your MWE. Are you sure that the code you posted leads to the erroneous behaviour? Please test this. If it actually does please put a `\listfiles` in your preamble and show the output from your log. Else please post the code which actually results in the shown output.

Comment: Make sure you have the `cm-super` fonts installed, or load the font package you want to use.

Comment: With your code I have the correct output (the arrow over omega symbol).

Comment: Thank you all for welcoming me on my first question. I've just updated my post with the extra info requested.

I don't know if \usepackage{amsfonts} is any good with respect to cm-fonts @Davislor cited.

I switched to offline LaTeX on Windows (Atom + MiKTeX) and hope to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: With your updated MWE, it still yields a good result. Maybe there are still some things in the preamble that lead to the problem.

Comment: Off-topic: you load `enumitem` package twice and also with different option(s). Delete one of them. However even with MWE as it is, is not possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, I've seen people having that kind of error because of the pdf viewer. Have you tried opening the output with your browser or any other application? You could also use the esvect package with the \vv command

Comment: Thank you to all of you! I couldn't imagine that using another PDF readers would have made the difference!